PHP cURL for Wordpress REST API gives rest_missing_callback_param
I want to list all the categories for my Wordpress site and get this information via the REST API. I generated the application password, that is what I want to use here. Sadly I don't seem to get this to work, I always get this error:
{"code":"rest_missing_callback_param","message":"Wrong parameter(s): name","data":{"status":400,"params":["name"]}}

This is my PHP code:
<?php

include 'db-connect.php';
$conn = OpenCon();
$conn -> set_charset("utf8");

$siteId = $_REQUEST["site-id"];

$sqlWebsite = "SELECT setting_value FROM ai_settings WHERE id = ".$siteId;

$queryWebsite = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlWebsite);
$rowWebsite = mysqli_fetch_row($queryWebsite);

$websiteArray = json_decode($rowWebsite[0]);

$site_url = "https://" . $websiteArray->url;
$username = $websiteArray->user;
$applicationPassword = $websiteArray->pass;

$categoriesEndpont = $site_url . '/wp-json/wp/v2/categories';

$headers = array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($username.":".$applicationPassword)
);

$data = array(
  'per_page' => '9999'
);

// get categories
$categoriesResponse = curlExecute($categoriesEndpont, $headers, $data);
print_r($categoriesResponse);

function curlExecute($url, $headers, $data = null)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  
  return $response;
}

?>

What am I missing? I'm lost... :S Thank you!

Generally speaking, to read data you want to send a GET request, and to write data you want a POST request. You are sending a POST request to that endpoint, which WordPress is interpreting as a "Create a Category" request, per the docs. Switch to a GET and it should work.

OMG, I was blind. I was creating a post before as a test, which was working. I did not change that :(
